How do I split a file at every occurrence of the NUL character?
I would like to split a file into multiple files, at every occurrence of the NUL character  in the original file (and discarding the NUL's).
So far I have tried the following, but the division is not based on the NULL character.
What should the call look like correctly?
csplit -z FILE /\0/ '{*}'

csplit -z FILE /\x00/ '{*}'


How should the new files be named?

This is not a programming question, but a question about how to use the csplit utility. It would be more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com.

thanks, I didn't know unix.stackexchange.com yet

Does the input file end with NUL (\0) or with LineFeed (\n) or neither? Should the output files end with a LineFeed or not? If the input file ends with LineFeed, should the final output file end in 0, 1 or 2 LineFeeds? Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you (you may find the od command useful for doing that).

how big is the file?

One of the file has 14GB.
The file contains \n, the last line break is not \n, at the end there is binary data

If the entire file fits comfortably in memory and bash version is > 4.3:
mapfile -d '' a <infile

n=${#a[@]}
for ((i=0; i<n; ++i)); do
    (( ${#a[i]} )) && printf '%s' "${a[i]}" >outfile.$i
done


read file into array using null as delimiter
write each array element that is not empty to next output file


If at least two consecutive chunks will fit in memory, then:
writeout(){
    (( ${#2} )) && printf '%s' "$2" >outfile.$1
    ((i)) && unset a[i]
}

i=0
mapfile -d '' -c1 -Cwriteout a <infile


read file into array using null as delimiter

execute callback function writeout on every chunk:

write chunk to next output file if it is not empty, and then
delete previous element of array






For files with chunks that don't fit in memory, GNU split has some non-standard extensions
that could be useful here.
Create a helper script myfilter:
#!/bin/bash
echo 1>&2 "writing output file: $FILE"
tr -d '\0' > "$FILE"
if ! [[ -s $FILE ]]; then
    echo 1>&2 "deleting empty file: $FILE"
    rm "$FILE"
fi

Then:
$ chmod +x myfilter
$ split -t'\0' -l1 -d --filter=./myfilter infile outfile.


split file using split

-t'\0' - set custom record separator
-l1 - write a single record per output file
-d - use numeric suffix
--filter=./myfilter - pipe each record into myfilter:

tr - copy input to $FILE (defined by split) while stripping nuls
delete $FILE if it ends up empty





Set -a if there could be a large number of output files.

I don't think csplit supports \x escapes in the regular expression.
You can do what you want using GNU awk (this may not work with other awks) with a script like this:
awk -v RS='\0' '{print $0 > "file"NR}' myfile.bin

This will create files file1, file2, etc with the contents of each NUL-delimited section. Since awk is designed primarily for text processing, I don't know if this solution has limitations around record size, content, etc.

Glad it helped! Please consider marking it as the accepted answer by checking the mark tot he left of the answer.

You should mention that requires GNU awk or similar to allow NUL as the RS.  Awk is a text processing tool and, per POSIX, text files do not contain NULs so we're into undefined behavior already plus many awk implementations are written in C where a NUL character terminates a string so they can't support a NUL inside a string. > "file"NR is also undefined behavior, it needs to be > ("file"NR) to be portable, and if you don't close() the output files as you go then most awks will fail with a "too many open files" error evenutally while GNU awk will slow down significantly handling them

I did already include a note about the fact that awk is meant for text processing in the answer :). I've updated it to specify GNU awk. It sounds like it worked out for the OP.

I don't think most newcomers would understand that "text processing" implicitly means "no NULs". The OPs probably using GNU awk but it's not only the OP who might find this answer in future if they have a similar question. '{out="file"NR; print > out; close(out)}' would be much more efficient (and portable) than {print $0 > "file"NR}' given large input.

I now use it as follows:
awk -v RS='\0' '{if (NR == 2) print $0}' FILE |python3 -c "import json,sys; j=json.load(sys.stdin); ... "

can awk print $0 at NR==2 and then abort?

@larsks I had already done this yesterday, but I get the following message: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

I have now changed it as follows:
awk -v RS='\0' '{if (NR == 2) {print $0; exit;}}' FILE |python3 -c "import json,sys; j=json.load(sys.stdin);…"
With the 14GB file, the execution time is acceptable.
real 0m0.051s user 0m0.048s sys 0m0.017s

One system has mawk installed, which seems to be slightly different from gawk. For 1 out of 15 files the result is wrong; mawk does not seem to recognize the NUL correctly for one file. When I look at the file, I can see the NUL characters, as with the other files.
The command looks like this for both systems: awk -v RS='\0' '{if (NR == 2) {print $0; exit;}}' FILE

Given this file (where each ^@ is a null):
cat -v file
chnk1^@chnk2^@
chunk3^@chunk4

I personally would turn to Ruby:
ruby -e '$<.read.split(/\u0000/).each.with_index(1){|chunk,i| 
    next if chunk.empty?
    f=File.open("chunk_#{i}.txt","w")
    f.write(chunk+"\n")
    f.close
}' file

Produces:
awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME ":"}1' chunk*.txt  
chunk_1.txt:
chnk1
chunk_2.txt:
chnk2
chunk_3.txt:

chunk3
chunk_4.txt:
chunk4

